# NDK: has not been declared

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am compiling the C++ code using Android native library NDK but I am getting the following errors while trying to include the [g729a.h](http://pastie.org/4737332) file in [g729_jni.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/issues/attachmentText?id=49&aid=7963991223373796529&name=g729_jni.cpp&token=srtLdoyAVixO0dz0ue5i3s-VlZ0:1347876617974):

**ERRORS:**

```
Compile++ arm    : g729_jni <= g729_jni.cpp
/usr/src/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/g729_jni/g729_jni.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__  -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -I/usr/src/android-ndk-r8/sources/cxx-stl/system/include -Ijni -DANDROID -O3 -Wa,--noexecstack   -O2 -DNDEBUG -g   -I/usr/src/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include -c  jni/g729_jni.cpp -o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/g729_jni/g729_jni.o 


In file included from jni/g729_jni.cpp:34:
jni/g729/g729a.h:70: error: 'UWord8' has not been declared
jni/g729/g729a.h:126: error: 'UWord8' has not been declared
jni/g729_jni.cpp: In function 'jint Java_org_sipdroid_codecs_G729_open(JNIEnv*, _jobject*)':
jni/g729_jni.cpp:72: error: 'UWord8' was not declared in this scope
jni/g729_jni.cpp: In function 'jint Java_org_sipdroid_codecs_G729_encode(JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jshortArray*, jint, _jbyteArray*, jint)':
jni/g729_jni.cpp:111: error: 'UWord8' was not declared in this scope
jni/g729_jni.cpp:111: error: expected ';' before 'serial'
jni/g729_jni.cpp:125: error: 'serial' was not declared in this scope
jni/g729_jni.cpp: In function 'jint Java_org_sipdroid_codecs_G729_decode(JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jbyteArray*, _jshortArray*, jint)':
jni/g729_jni.cpp:156: error: cannot convert 'unsigned char*' to 'int*' for argument '2' to 'void g729a_dec_process(void*, int*, Word16*, Flag)'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/g729_jni/g729_jni.o] Error 1
```

I googled to try and find the reason behind this error. As C++ is case sensitive, if we make a mistake in upper and lower case, then this kind of error occurs. But I didn't make this kind of mistakes.

If you have any idea or suggestion then please guide me through that.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
[root@localhost sipdroid-read-only]# /usr/src/android-ndk-r8/ndk-build V=1 APP_ABI=armeabi APP_PROJECT_PATH=. obj/local/armeabi/objs/g729_jni/g729_jni.o
make: `obj/local/armeabi/objs/g729_jni/g729_jni.o' is up to date.
```

Comment: Please run **ndk-build** with parameter **V=1** to echo the commands, and publish the compilation step that causes the reported errors.

Comment: Oops, my fault in copy/paste. Remove `.cmd`, as I have fixed in my answer (`ndk-build.cmd` is for Windows). If you see `g729_jni.o is up to date.`, your previous build succeeded. You can always run `ndk-build clean` and try again.

Comment: its fine,but still i am getting the same message `g729_jni.o is up to date` and what fix is needed after line 89 of Android.mk

Comment: I guess your **Android.mk** is different from what I got from `http://sipdroid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`. Please publish your version, or follow exactly the steps in my answer and report the results.

Comment: i am using the source of sipdroid  2.7 beta

Comment: Hey i got one link in which they have created .so file of `g729` for `armeabi-v7a` which is not working in `armeabi` devices. do you have any idea what changes should be made to work that on `armeabi` devices?

Comment: Sorry, I am not at my desk right now, and won't get to it until Monday. But I have a strong feeling that you do not try to follow my advice anyway.

Comment: its fine, you already helped me a lot thank you very much for that and yeah i am trying to find the solution if i get any then okay otherwise I'll let you know the problems.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your last comment. of course i had followed your advice and steps. and that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your typedef.h is similar to http://siphon.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/g729a/Headers/typedef.h

Here are the steps I made to reproduce your problem:

```
svn checkout http://sipdroid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ sipdroid
cd sipdroid
sed "s/^SILK/include $(CLEAR_VARS)\\nSILK/" -i jni/Android.mk
```

(note that Android.mk needed a fix after line 89).

```
svn checkout http://siphon.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ ../siphon
cp -d ../siphon/g729a/Headers/ jni/g729
wget http://pastie.org/pastes/4737332/download -O jni/g729/g729a.h
wget "http://sipdroid.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=7963991223373796529&name=g729_jni.cpp&token=KHEZCoq6ZYSuV_VhsV8fC3uwsSs%3A1348058591979" -O jni/g729_jni.cpp
sed -e "s/g722_jni/g729_jni/" -i jni/Android.mk
ndk-build.cmd V=1 APP_ABI=armeabi APP_PROJECT_PATH=. obj/local/armeabi/objs/g729_jni/g729_jni.o
```

... and your file compiles with a small warning. What have you done differently?

Comment: yeah its same,actually i am using the source of siphon,i just added one new file which is g729a.h

Comment: You **#include** jni/g729/g729a.h inside **extern "C"** but the file itself is C++ aware. Try to compile with this **#include** moved out of the **extern "C"** brackets of g729_jni.cpp

Comment: i tried with that put this #include "g729/g729a.h" out of extern "C" and got more errors.[see this](http://pastie.org/4753077)

Comment: It's strange.. For me it all works like charm... Please see the updated answer for step-by-step instructions. Somewhere we do things differently...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support,i will try with this and let you know if i found any problem. And yes i have download the g729 source from ITU official site but in that g729a.h file was not there so i used siphon's g729a.h file.

Comment: seems you have already worked on g729,SIP and VoIP, didn't you?

Comment: i have tested with that please see my update,i have tried with that commands.